# Why sRGB extension has lost a constant?

Tags: webgl, webgl2, webgl-extensions

Old WebGL context has `EXT_sRGB` extension. That extension exposes 4 constants:

```
{
  SRGB_EXT : 35904, 
  SRGB_ALPHA_EXT : 35906, 
  SRGB8_ALPHA8_EXT : 35907, 
  FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_COLOR_ENCODING_EXT : 33296
}
```

The extension was promoted in WebGL2 and became part of the core, but has lost a constant. WebGL2 has only constants :

```
{
  SRGB : 35904, 
  SRGB8_ALPHA8 : 35907, 
  FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_COLOR_ENCODING : 33296  
}
```

No `SRGB_ALPHA`. More over WebGL2 context has none constant with value 35906.  I did check both browsers, the situation is same. Also, I checked all other extensions I had locally. All promoted extensions in WebGL2 have merged all their properties into context, but sRGB. Has not found much in docs.

What's wrong with **sRGB** extension and what reasoning is behind the loss? 
Did anyone use **SRGB_ALPHA_EXT** constant? How? Please share your experience.

Also, something weird happened with **disjoint_timer_query** extension. That extension was merged in partially. WebGL2 context got some properties of the extension. I have `disjoint_timer_query_webgl2` in Chrome which has all missing properties except one `getQueryObject` which was renamed to `getQueryParameter`, but in Firefox `disjoint_timer_query` extension is still available with WebGL2 context.

Answer (score 1):

WebGL2 isn't 100% backward compatible with WebGL1. More like 99%. You found an area that's not.

`SRGB_ALPHA_EXT` is an unsized format and unsized formats have for the most part been deprecated. The basic non-extension unsized formats still exist but there's a table in the OpenGL ES 3.0 spec specifying what effective sized internal format they become. Extension unsized formats are not covered.

The constants are just that, constant, so you're free to define them in your own code.

```
const srgba8InternalFormat = 35907;
const srgba8Format = isWebGL2 ? 6408 : 35906;
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE2D, 0, srgba8InternalFormat, width, height, 0
              srgba8Format, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0
```

In other words you don't have to reference the constants off of a `WebGLRenderingContext`. Bonus: your code will run faster and be smaller.

Comment: So are you saying, despite the fact that 35906 constant was dropped from WebGL2, it is still useful, and WebGL2 understands it? Probably, that is not what you meant.

Comment: Thank you @gman. Still not clear enough. Can or cant one use 35906 constant in WebGL1? Can or cant one use 35906 constant in WebGL2? Can use another instead?

Comment: Read the code. In WebGL1 it's using 35906 (`SRGB_ALPHA_EXT`). In WebGL2 it using 6408 (`RGBA`). You can only use 35906 in WebGL1 and only if you enabled the extension. In WebGL2 you can NOT use 35906

Comment: Clear. Is it possible to use some other constant in WebbGL1 instead of 35906 with the same outcome?